# JSON Serialization using Codable in Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, serialization, swift4, codable

I am working on a stock market quoting app which should display real-time stock price. I am using this API which returns JSON with a dynamic key being the current time. I am not sure how I can use this key to get the data because it keeps changing based on current time. Following is the JSON response I get from the API. Codable asks for a string literal as a key and I am not sure how I can hard code this `"2017-12-20 16:00:00"`key.

```
{
"Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "Intraday (1min) prices and volumes",
    "2. Symbol": "MSFT",
    "3. Last Refreshed": "2017-12-20 16:00:00",
    "4. Interval": "1min",
    "5. Output Size": "Compact",
    "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
},
"Time Series (1min)": {
    `"2017-12-20 16:00:00"`: {
        "1. open": "85.5600",
        "2. high": "85.7000",
        "3. low": "85.5200",
        "4. close": "85.5200",
        "5. volume": "410337"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:59:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5999",
        "2. high": "85.5999",
        "3. low": "85.5400",
        "4. close": "85.5550",
        "5. volume": "99376"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:58:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5700",
        "2. high": "85.6000",
        "3. low": "85.5650",
        "4. close": "85.5900",
        "5. volume": "63229"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:57:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5400",
        "2. high": "85.5800",
        "3. low": "85.5350",
        "4. close": "85.5750",
        "5. volume": "51367"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:56:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5650",
        "2. high": "85.5700",
        "3. low": "85.5400",
        "4. close": "85.5400",
        "5. volume": "72494"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:55:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5700",
        "2. high": "85.5700",
        "3. low": "85.5600",
        "4. close": "85.5650",
        "5. volume": "24096"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:54:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5650",
        "2. high": "85.5700",
        "3. low": "85.5600",
        "4. close": "85.5700",
        "5. volume": "18411"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:53:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5450",
        "2. high": "85.5700",
        "3. low": "85.5400",
        "4. close": "85.5650",
        "5. volume": "27636"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:52:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5469",
        "2. high": "85.5500",
        "3. low": "85.5400",
        "4. close": "85.5400",
        "5. volume": "29917"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:51:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5200",
        "2. high": "85.5500",
        "3. low": "85.5200",
        "4. close": "85.5500",
        "5. volume": "48733"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:50:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5250",
        "2. high": "85.5600",
        "3. low": "85.5100",
        "4. close": "85.5200",
        "5. volume": "46797"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:49:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5150",
        "2. high": "85.5300",
        "3. low": "85.5000",
        "4. close": "85.5211",
        "5. volume": "20646"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:48:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5200",
        "2. high": "85.5300",
        "3. low": "85.5100",
        "4. close": "85.5150",
        "5. volume": "24087"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:47:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5400",
        "2. high": "85.5400",
        "3. low": "85.5300",
        "4. close": "85.5300",
        "5. volume": "8844"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:46:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5950",
        "2. high": "85.6000",
        "3. low": "85.5400",
        "4. close": "85.5400",
        "5. volume": "68527"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:45:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5650",
        "2. high": "85.6000",
        "3. low": "85.5600",
        "4. close": "85.5950",
        "5. volume": "29548"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:44:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5750",
        "2. high": "85.5800",
        "3. low": "85.5600",
        "4. close": "85.5650",
        "5. volume": "35151"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:43:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5700",
        "2. high": "85.5800",
        "3. low": "85.5600",
        "4. close": "85.5700",
        "5. volume": "21540"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:42:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5700",
        "2. high": "85.5800",
        "3. low": "85.5590",
        "4. close": "85.5650",
        "5. volume": "31371"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:41:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5350",
        "2. high": "85.5700",
        "3. low": "85.5349",
        "4. close": "85.5700",
        "5. volume": "39099"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:40:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5400",
        "2. high": "85.5450",
        "3. low": "85.5300",
        "4. close": "85.5350",
        "5. volume": "26058"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:39:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5500",
        "2. high": "85.5699",
        "3. low": "85.5400",
        "4. close": "85.5400",
        "5. volume": "23070"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:38:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5000",
        "2. high": "85.5700",
        "3. low": "85.4901",
        "4. close": "85.5600",
        "5. volume": "50136"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:37:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4901",
        "2. high": "85.5100",
        "3. low": "85.4850",
        "4. close": "85.5000",
        "5. volume": "53336"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:36:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4900",
        "2. high": "85.5050",
        "3. low": "85.4850",
        "4. close": "85.4950",
        "5. volume": "69050"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:35:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5000",
        "2. high": "85.5100",
        "3. low": "85.4900",
        "4. close": "85.4900",
        "5. volume": "198091"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:34:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4823",
        "2. high": "85.5050",
        "3. low": "85.4700",
        "4. close": "85.5000",
        "5. volume": "31054"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:33:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4815",
        "2. high": "85.4950",
        "3. low": "85.4700",
        "4. close": "85.4900",
        "5. volume": "25969"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:32:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4801",
        "2. high": "85.4900",
        "3. low": "85.4700",
        "4. close": "85.4850",
        "5. volume": "30045"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:31:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4700",
        "2. high": "85.4950",
        "3. low": "85.4700",
        "4. close": "85.4900",
        "5. volume": "18800"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:30:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4800",
        "2. high": "85.5000",
        "3. low": "85.4700",
        "4. close": "85.4750",
        "5. volume": "28925"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:29:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5100",
        "2. high": "85.5150",
        "3. low": "85.4750",
        "4. close": "85.4800",
        "5. volume": "38660"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:28:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5100",
        "2. high": "85.5400",
        "3. low": "85.5100",
        "4. close": "85.5150",
        "5. volume": "30167"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:27:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5400",
        "2. high": "85.5400",
        "3. low": "85.5100",
        "4. close": "85.5150",
        "5. volume": "12916"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:26:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5450",
        "2. high": "85.5500",
        "3. low": "85.5300",
        "4. close": "85.5350",
        "5. volume": "15679"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:25:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5050",
        "2. high": "85.5500",
        "3. low": "85.5010",
        "4. close": "85.5450",
        "5. volume": "19532"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:24:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5000",
        "2. high": "85.5150",
        "3. low": "85.4900",
        "4. close": "85.5003",
        "5. volume": "114808"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:23:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5000",
        "2. high": "85.5100",
        "3. low": "85.4900",
        "4. close": "85.5050",
        "5. volume": "65535"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:22:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4950",
        "2. high": "85.5000",
        "3. low": "85.4900",
        "4. close": "85.5000",
        "5. volume": "9777"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:21:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4750",
        "2. high": "85.5000",
        "3. low": "85.4700",
        "4. close": "85.4950",
        "5. volume": "26052"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:20:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5000",
        "2. high": "85.5000",
        "3. low": "85.4750",
        "4. close": "85.4750",
        "5. volume": "9043"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:19:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5150",
        "2. high": "85.5300",
        "3. low": "85.5050",
        "4. close": "85.5050",
        "5. volume": "173022"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:18:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5150",
        "2. high": "85.5300",
        "3. low": "85.5100",
        "4. close": "85.5100",
        "5. volume": "18500"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:17:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4950",
        "2. high": "85.5200",
        "3. low": "85.4900",
        "4. close": "85.5150",
        "5. volume": "10224"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:16:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5250",
        "2. high": "85.5250",
        "3. low": "85.4800",
        "4. close": "85.4900",
        "5. volume": "33393"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:15:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5150",
        "2. high": "85.5300",
        "3. low": "85.5100",
        "4. close": "85.5250",
        "5. volume": "22149"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:14:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5250",
        "2. high": "85.5300",
        "3. low": "85.5100",
        "4. close": "85.5150",
        "5. volume": "14553"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:13:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4900",
        "2. high": "85.5300",
        "3. low": "85.4900",
        "4. close": "85.5300",
        "5. volume": "25674"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:12:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4800",
        "2. high": "85.5000",
        "3. low": "85.4700",
        "4. close": "85.4900",
        "5. volume": "44503"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:11:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5300",
        "2. high": "85.5350",
        "3. low": "85.4800",
        "4. close": "85.4800",
        "5. volume": "27403"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:10:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5600",
        "2. high": "85.5800",
        "3. low": "85.5300",
        "4. close": "85.5300",
        "5. volume": "38154"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:09:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5344",
        "2. high": "85.5700",
        "3. low": "85.5200",
        "4. close": "85.5650",
        "5. volume": "53794"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:08:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5500",
        "2. high": "85.5500",
        "3. low": "85.5300",
        "4. close": "85.5400",
        "5. volume": "9832"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:07:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5900",
        "2. high": "85.5900",
        "3. low": "85.5500",
        "4. close": "85.5500",
        "5. volume": "27184"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:06:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5750",
        "2. high": "85.5950",
        "3. low": "85.5700",
        "4. close": "85.5900",
        "5. volume": "51431"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:05:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5500",
        "2. high": "85.5750",
        "3. low": "85.5400",
        "4. close": "85.5750",
        "5. volume": "22700"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:04:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5400",
        "2. high": "85.5500",
        "3. low": "85.5300",
        "4. close": "85.5500",
        "5. volume": "15989"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:03:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5200",
        "2. high": "85.5400",
        "3. low": "85.5200",
        "4. close": "85.5350",
        "5. volume": "16326"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:02:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5400",
        "2. high": "85.5400",
        "3. low": "85.5100",
        "4. close": "85.5250",
        "5. volume": "24200"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:01:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5200",
        "2. high": "85.5400",
        "3. low": "85.5150",
        "4. close": "85.5400",
        "5. volume": "17386"
    },
    "2017-12-20 15:00:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5100",
        "2. high": "85.5200",
        "3. low": "85.5000",
        "4. close": "85.5200",
        "5. volume": "17650"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:59:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4950",
        "2. high": "85.5100",
        "3. low": "85.4900",
        "4. close": "85.5000",
        "5. volume": "29647"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:58:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4900",
        "2. high": "85.5100",
        "3. low": "85.4800",
        "4. close": "85.4966",
        "5. volume": "25197"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:57:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4300",
        "2. high": "85.4900",
        "3. low": "85.4200",
        "4. close": "85.4850",
        "5. volume": "42575"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:56:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4150",
        "2. high": "85.4400",
        "3. low": "85.4150",
        "4. close": "85.4350",
        "5. volume": "24684"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:55:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4500",
        "2. high": "85.4500",
        "3. low": "85.4032",
        "4. close": "85.4150",
        "5. volume": "26693"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:54:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4400",
        "2. high": "85.4500",
        "3. low": "85.4400",
        "4. close": "85.4450",
        "5. volume": "26912"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:53:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4700",
        "2. high": "85.4700",
        "3. low": "85.4400",
        "4. close": "85.4401",
        "5. volume": "22234"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:52:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4599",
        "2. high": "85.4900",
        "3. low": "85.4550",
        "4. close": "85.4750",
        "5. volume": "24890"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:51:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4500",
        "2. high": "85.4750",
        "3. low": "85.4500",
        "4. close": "85.4550",
        "5. volume": "23949"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:50:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4400",
        "2. high": "85.4600",
        "3. low": "85.4100",
        "4. close": "85.4550",
        "5. volume": "55829"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:49:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4800",
        "2. high": "85.4900",
        "3. low": "85.4400",
        "4. close": "85.4450",
        "5. volume": "33761"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:48:00": {
        "1. open": "85.5000",
        "2. high": "85.5100",
        "3. low": "85.4850",
        "4. close": "85.4850",
        "5. volume": "36582"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:47:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4800",
        "2. high": "85.5000",
        "3. low": "85.4750",
        "4. close": "85.5000",
        "5. volume": "15721"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:46:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4501",
        "2. high": "85.4800",
        "3. low": "85.4500",
        "4. close": "85.4750",
        "5. volume": "13905"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:45:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4600",
        "2. high": "85.4700",
        "3. low": "85.4500",
        "4. close": "85.4550",
        "5. volume": "9723"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:44:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4850",
        "2. high": "85.4850",
        "3. low": "85.4500",
        "4. close": "85.4600",
        "5. volume": "26091"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:43:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4656",
        "2. high": "85.4800",
        "3. low": "85.4463",
        "4. close": "85.4800",
        "5. volume": "17170"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:42:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4400",
        "2. high": "85.4700",
        "3. low": "85.4400",
        "4. close": "85.4600",
        "5. volume": "10626"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:41:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4400",
        "2. high": "85.4450",
        "3. low": "85.4250",
        "4. close": "85.4400",
        "5. volume": "24499"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:40:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4690",
        "2. high": "85.4700",
        "3. low": "85.4400",
        "4. close": "85.4400",
        "5. volume": "10785"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:39:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4600",
        "2. high": "85.4700",
        "3. low": "85.4500",
        "4. close": "85.4650",
        "5. volume": "16359"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:38:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4569",
        "2. high": "85.4700",
        "3. low": "85.4300",
        "4. close": "85.4700",
        "5. volume": "23311"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:37:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4570",
        "2. high": "85.4600",
        "3. low": "85.4500",
        "4. close": "85.4600",
        "5. volume": "12219"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:36:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4250",
        "2. high": "85.4600",
        "3. low": "85.4250",
        "4. close": "85.4500",
        "5. volume": "22127"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:35:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4300",
        "2. high": "85.4350",
        "3. low": "85.4200",
        "4. close": "85.4250",
        "5. volume": "11056"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:34:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4300",
        "2. high": "85.4450",
        "3. low": "85.4200",
        "4. close": "85.4250",
        "5. volume": "28787"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:33:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4100",
        "2. high": "85.4300",
        "3. low": "85.4050",
        "4. close": "85.4300",
        "5. volume": "8147"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:32:00": {
        "1. open": "85.3950",
        "2. high": "85.4100",
        "3. low": "85.3950",
        "4. close": "85.4100",
        "5. volume": "33362"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:31:00": {
        "1. open": "85.3700",
        "2. high": "85.4000",
        "3. low": "85.3700",
        "4. close": "85.4000",
        "5. volume": "19334"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:30:00": {
        "1. open": "85.3500",
        "2. high": "85.3750",
        "3. low": "85.3450",
        "4. close": "85.3750",
        "5. volume": "20360"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:29:00": {
        "1. open": "85.3400",
        "2. high": "85.3600",
        "3. low": "85.3150",
        "4. close": "85.3500",
        "5. volume": "32113"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:28:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4100",
        "2. high": "85.4150",
        "3. low": "85.3400",
        "4. close": "85.3400",
        "5. volume": "43092"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:27:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4400",
        "2. high": "85.4456",
        "3. low": "85.4000",
        "4. close": "85.4100",
        "5. volume": "35043"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:26:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4600",
        "2. high": "85.4800",
        "3. low": "85.4400",
        "4. close": "85.4400",
        "5. volume": "20475"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:25:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4800",
        "2. high": "85.4800",
        "3. low": "85.4550",
        "4. close": "85.4600",
        "5. volume": "21708"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:24:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4300",
        "2. high": "85.4800",
        "3. low": "85.4200",
        "4. close": "85.4750",
        "5. volume": "23663"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:23:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4399",
        "2. high": "85.4400",
        "3. low": "85.4200",
        "4. close": "85.4300",
        "5. volume": "11003"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:22:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4400",
        "2. high": "85.4500",
        "3. low": "85.4300",
        "4. close": "85.4400",
        "5. volume": "23527"
    },
    "2017-12-20 14:21:00": {
        "1. open": "85.4150",
        "2. high": "85.4500",
        "3. low": "85.4150",
        "4. close": "85.4450",
        "5. volume": "19001"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You have to decode `[String : CustomClass]` to get a dictionary or write a custom initializer to put keys and values together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using KeyedDecodingContainer to decode an object with a random key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47913410/using-keyeddecodingcontainer-to-decode-an-object-with-a-random-key)